# System functionality lost after my compilation of glib 2.0 and Gstreamer

Tags: gstreamer, glib

It seems that my Ubuntu 14.4 LTS lost lots of functionality after my compilation of glib 2.0 and the latest Gstreamer.

Multimedia, IME, auto-mount and many other functionality have lost since then.

How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't just compile, you must have installed these libraries system-wide. You should try to uninstall whatever you did install, and reinstall the packages from your package manager.

Comment: Yes I did. And now I have reinstalled the whole OS.

Comment: nuking from orbit is a sane approach, not using the latest ubuntu is too if you plan to make serious work with h264 streams is too ;)